# Is Sitecore Campaign Creator tool supported in Sitecore 9

Tags: campaigncreator

I see the campaign creator tool under Sitecore XP 9 documentation.

But in the [compatibility table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/541788) Campaign Creator tool is not supported for Sitecore 9.

Is it supported for Sitecore 9 or not?

Answer (score 2):

Campaign Creator was integrated into Sitecore from version Sitecore 8.1 ([See Release notes](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/Sitecore%2081/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2081%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes)). It is not anymore a separate module:

[image]

- You can start it from Launchpad:

[image]

- Take a look in this documentation for further details:

  - https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/campaigns/campaigns/the_campaign_creator
  - https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/Sitecore%2081/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2081%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes